# Publisher finishes before subscriber and messages are lost - why?

Tags: zeromq

Fairly new to zeromq and trying to get a basic pub/sub to work. When I run the following (sub starting before pub) the publisher finishes but the subscriber hangs having not received all the messages - why ?

I think the socket is being closed but the messages have been sent ? Is there a way of ensuring all messages are received ?

Publisher:

```
import zmq
import random
import time
import tnetstring

context=zmq.Context()
socket=context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5556")

y=0
for x in xrange(5000):
    st = random.randrange(1,10) 
    data = []
    data.append(random.randrange(1,100000))
    data.append(int(time.time()))
    data.append(random.uniform(1.0,10.0))

    s = tnetstring.dumps(data)
    print 'Sending ...%d %s' % (st,s)

    socket.send("%d %s" % (st,s))
    print "Messages sent: %d" % x
    y+=1

print '*** SERVER FINISHED. # MESSAGES SENT = ' + str(y)
```

Subscriber :-

```
import sys
import zmq
import tnetstring

# Socket to talk to server
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5556")
filter = "" # get all messages

socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, filter)

x=0
while True:
    topic,data = socket.recv().split()
    print "Topic: %s, Data = %s. Total # Messages = %d" % (topic,data,x)
    x+=1
```

Comment: Resolved: this is an example of the "slow joiner" situation and that is described very well in Chapter 2 of the docs - http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:all#sockets-and-patterns. In particular, it states :

"There is one more important thing to know about PUB-SUB sockets: you do not know precisely when a subscriber starts to get messages. **Even if you start a subscriber**, wait a while, and then start the publisher, the subscriber will always miss the first messages that the publisher sends..."

Comment: You should alos look at http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter5, as it illustrates how to achieve more reliable pub/sub patterns.

Answer (score 0):

In ZeroMQ, clients and servers always try to reconnect; they won't go down if the other side disconnects (because in many cases you'd want them to resume talking if the other side comes up again). So in your test code, the client will just wait until the server starts sending messages again, unless you stop `recv()`ing messages at some point.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific instance, you may want to investigate using the socket.close() and context.term(). It will block until all the messages have been sent. You also have the problem of a slow joiner. You can add a sleep after the bind, but before you start publishing. This works in a test case, but you will want to really understand what is the solution vs a band-aid.

You need to think of the PUB/SUB pattern like a radio. The sender and receiver are both asynchronous. The Publisher will continue to send even if no one is listening. The subscriber will only receive data if it is listening. If the network goes down in the middle, the data will be lost.

You need to understand this in order to design your messages. For example, if you design your messages to be "idempotent", it doesn't matter if you lose data. An example of this would be a status type message. It doesn't matter if you have any of the previous statuses. The latest one is correct and message loss doesn't matter. The benefits to this approach is that you end up with a more robust and performant system. The downsides are when you can't design your messages this way.

Your example includes a type of message that requires no loss. Another type of message would be transactional. For example, if you just sent the deltas of what changed in your system, you would not be able to lose the messages. Database replication is often managed this way which is why db replication is often so fragile. To try to provide guarantees, you need to do a couple things. One thing is to add a persistent cache. Each message sent needs to be logged in the persistent cache. Each message needs to be assigned a unique id (preferably a sequence) so that the clients can determine if they are missing a message. A second socket (ROUTER/REQ) needs to be added for the client to request the missing messages individually. Alternatively, you could just use the secondary socket to request resending over the PUB/SUB. The clients would then all receive the messages again (which works for the multicast version). The clients would ignore the messages they had already seen. NOTE: this follows the MAJORDOMO pattern found in the ZeroMQ guide.

An alternative approach is to create your own broker using the ROUTER/DEALER sockets. When the ROUTER socket saw each DEALER connect, it would store its ID. When the ROUTER needed to send data, it would iterate over all client IDs and publish the message. Each message should contain a sequence so that the client can know what missing messages to request. NOTE: this is a sort of reimplementation of Kafka from linkedin.

Comment: Part of this answer is copied from the 0MQ documentation. Please link the source: http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter5#Pros-and-Cons-of-Pub-Sub

Comment: I don't remember copying. What part was copied?